# Three different result for the same indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, graphing-functions

I was killing time solving some indefinite integrals, when I found this one:
\begin{equation}
  \int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\ \mathrm{d}x
  \tag{1}\label{integral}
\end{equation}
Not a particularly difficult one, I'll post my solution here:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\ \mathrm{d}x = \int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}}\ \mathrm{d}x
  \end{split}
\tag{2}\label{calculus}
\end{equation}
by substituting $t = x+1$, d$t = \mathrm{d}x$, and then $s = \sqrt{t^2-1} \rightarrow \mathrm{d}s = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\mathrm{d}t$

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
   = \int\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}\ \mathrm{d}t &= \int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}}\ \mathrm{d}x =\\
  &= \int\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{1+s^2} =\\
  &= \arctan{s} + \mathrm{cost}\\
  &= \arctan{\sqrt{t^2-1}} + \mathrm{cost}\\
  &= \arctan{\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^2-1}} + \mathrm{cost}
  \end{split}
\tag{3}\label{calculus2}
\end{equation}

I then derived (I recommend, if you wanna check my results to use this [online derivative calculator](http://www.derivative-calculator.net/) which actually shows steps...) my solution finding the starting function:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\arctan{\sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}} + \mathrm{cost}) = \frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}$$

The graph (plotted with Grapher from Mac Os X), with $\color{red}{\text{function}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{integral}}$ :

[image: Plot1]

Now this integral comes from the exercise book Problems in Mathematical Analysis by Boris Demidovich and it's the number **1271**, and even if I'm pretty sure this mine is the correct solution I lost quite time to understand the proposed solution of the book, which, if you don't have it and you can't check for yourself, is

**1271**. $\qquad-\arcsin(\frac{1}{1+x})$

deriving this function you'll find:

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}&\left[-\arcsin(\frac{1}{1+x})\right] =\\
  &= \dfrac{1}{\left(x+1\right)^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\left(x+1\right)^2}}}\\
  &= \dfrac{1}{\frac{\left(x+1\right)^2}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2}}\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^2-1}}\\
 &= \dfrac{1}{\frac{\left(x+1\right)^2}{|x+1|}\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^2-1}}\\
 &= \dfrac{1}{{\left(x+1\right)}\mathrm{sgn}(x+1)\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^2-1}}\\
  \end{split}
\tag{4}\label{calculus3}
\end{equation}

Plotting the result will give you an idea about the mistakte he could have done, in cyan the $\color{cyan}{Demidovich's~~primitive}$:

[image]

So I was pretty sure I was right and he was not, so I tried integrate the \eqref{integral} with Mathematica, with another unsatisfying outcome:

\begin{equation}
  \int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+2}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+2}})}{\sqrt{x(x+2)}}
\end{equation}

This solution, in $\color{orange}{orange}$, is almost like mine, even if it does not comprehend the negative values of the function...

[image]

Also, if I try to derive (I've done it with calculator, as it's quite long to do for yourself...) you get
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+2}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+2}})}{\sqrt{x(x+2)}}\right)' = $$
$$-\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{x+2}\left(-x^\frac{7}{2}-3x^\frac{5}{2}-2x^\frac{3}{2}\right)+\left(x+2\right)^\frac{3}{2}\left(x^\frac{5}{2}+x^\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\right)-x^3-4x^2-4x}{\left(x\left(x+2\right)\right)^\frac{3}{2}\left(x^2+3x+2\right)}$$

Now, since I've found that in my range of definition $x^2-2x>0$ the primitive function that i found, derived, gives me the starting function, this should tell me that I am right and others (computer, this case) have bugs or they encounter problems deriving such a function. So which of the three solution $\color{blue}{mine}$, $\color{orange}{Mathematica's}$ or $\color{cyan}{Demidovich's}$ is the correct one? Why are them wrong, if they are? Does it depend on calculator's bug or it's my problem?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: on the last one $2\sqrt x \sqrt {x+2} \cdots$ and not $(\sqrt 2\sqrt x \cdots$ and then it will tie out, at least it will for $x\ge0$  all three tie out $x\ge 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression provided by *Mathematica* simplifies in the case where $x < -2$ or $x > 0$:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[1/((x + 1) Sqrt[x^2 + 2 x]), x], x^2 + 2 x > 0]
```

gives $$2 \tan^{-1} \sqrt{\frac{x}{x+2}}.$$  This is equivalent to your antiderivative on $x > 0$, and differs from your antiderivative by a constant factor on $x < -2$.  Therefore, they are equivalent.  What is clearly wrong is the "Demidovich" solution for $x < -2$:  the antiderivative cannot be increasing when $x$ is negative.

Comment: But if it differs from my antiderivative by a constant one of the two solutions it's not correct... who's right?

Answer (score 1):

Noting that $\sqrt{x^2+2x}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}$, it seem sensible to try $x+1=\sec(u)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac1{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\frac1{\sec(u)\tan(u)}\sec(u)\tan(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=u+C\\[8pt]
&=\sec^{-1}(x+1)+C
\end{align}
$$
Of course, the branch of $\sec^{-1}$ needs to be chosen to be in the third quadrant when its argument is negative (since $\sec(u)=x+1\le0$ and  $\tan(u)=\sqrt{x^2+2x}\ge0$). If we want to use the standard choice for $\sec^{-1}$ for negative arguments, we can alter the answer to be
$$
\int\frac1{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\operatorname{sgn}(x+1)\sec^{-1}(x+1)+C
$$

Comment: The $\sec^{-1}(x+1)$ function derivative gives me the same solution of Wolfram $$\dfrac{1}{\left(x+1\right)^2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\left(x+1\right)^2}}},$$ which is not the starting function... Plus $\sec^{-1}(x+1)$ increases as $x$ approaches -1, which is clear not possible as its derivative (the starting function) goes to $-\infty$ as $x\rightarrow-1^-$...

Also there aren't branches in the third quadrant as you can notice by plotting that function.

Comment: That *is* the starting function for $x\gt0$. For $x\lt-2$, Wolfram is taking the wrong branch of $\sec^{-1}(x+1)$. For $x\lt-2$, $\sec^{-1}(x+1)$ can be in the second or third quadrant. The usual choice is the second quadrant, so if you want to use the usual choice for $\sec^{-1}(x+1)$, you can alter the answer to use $\operatorname{sgn(x+1)}\sec^{-1}(x+1)$.

Comment: So, basically, it's all matter of notation for the function $\sec^{-1}$? Also, is my result $\arctan{(\sqrt{x^2-2x})}$ right as well as your? If it is, why their graphs differ (even if only for a constant)? Thanks for your attention so much...

Comment: @opisthofulax: indefinite integrals can be known up to an additive constant. This is why we say $\int x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12x^2\color{#C00}{+C}$. Since the derivative of any constant is $0$, the antiderivative of $0$ can be any constant.

Comment: Yes, of course I know, but I was a little bit confused as the two different solutions do not have $\color{red}{+C)$, but look much more different, so actually I said that they differ for a constant only when I looked at the graph solving my doubt without noticing it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The primitives exist at $(-\infty,-2)$, and $(0,+\infty) $.

> at $(0,+\infty) $ we put

$$x+1=\cosh (t) $$ 
the integral becomes

$$I=\int \frac {\sinh (t)dt}{\cosh (t)\sinh (t)} $$

$$=\int \frac {2e^t}{1+e^{2t}} $$
$$=2\arctan(e^t)+C $$

with
$$e^{2t}-2 (x+1)e^t+1=0$$
$$t=\ln ((x+1)+\sqrt {x^2+2x})$$

thus

> $$I=2\arctan((x+1)+\sqrt {x^2+2x})+C $$

At $(-\infty,-2) $

we put $x+1=-\cosh (t) $.
You can finish.

Comment: You're saying that dividing the ranges of definition before integrate will change the result? I derivate your result and I got the same starting function that i find if i derive my solution... Are we both right? How's it possible? Of course exists an entire family of antiderivatives, but they're plus a constant, not different functions such as your $\arctan{\left((x+1) + \sqrt{x^2+2x}\right)}$ and $\arctan{(\sqrt{x^2+2x})}$...

Am I missing something?

Comment: @opisthofulax Yes. try to integrate $\frac {1}{\sqrt {|x^2-1|}} $.